# Bash find, exclude parent?

Tags: bash, find, dotfiles

I have a folder with some dotfiles I would like to make symlinks for. I cannot see an easy way to do this.

`ls -a ~/dotfiles` will include the dotfiles, but also `.` and `..`

`find ~/dotfiles -maxdepth 1` will include the dotfiles, but also `~/dotfiles`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Based off [MvanGeest’s](/users/347934) comment this appears to work.

```
find ~/dotfiles -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1
```

This looks to do the job as well

```
ls -A ~/dotfiles
```

Comment: +1 I was about to post an answer with `ls`'s -A option until I saw this.

Comment: @StevenPenny I was using BSD find rather than GNU find, you are right, and I'll change my scripts accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to find dot files, ie. Files that start with a "."  and have a second character that is not a ".". This should do the job:

```
find . -name '.[^.]*'
```

to link all found files to /path/to/dir:

```
find $PWD -name '.[^.]*' -exec ln -s '{}' /path/to/dir \;
```

Note that "$PWD" produces an absolute path, as symlinks to relative paths will most likely point into nirvana...